# Encoding error in LXML etree.iterparse() but not in etree.parse()

Tags: python, xml, encoding, lxml, iterparse

I am trying to parse a ~200MB XML file using LXML. I was stupidly doing `etree.parse(xml_path)`, without any `encoding` parameter as argument, and then using `iterwalk()` to iterate over some child nodes, thinking that it would lower memory consumption. It worked, and I could parse my entire XML file, albeit very slowly. Then I realized that on doing `etree.parse(xml_path)`, the entire file is loaded in memory, so doing `iterparse()` or `iterwalk()` after that doesn't make sense.

So now, I am trying to directly do `etree.iterparse(xml_path)` on the same file but I am getting

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x93 in position 5123: invalid start byte
```

I tried using both `encoding='utf-8'` and `encoding='ISO-8859-1'` as arguments in `iterparse()` but the error still remains. My XML file states that the encoding is `'ISO-8859-1'`.

**TL;DR:** `etree.parse()` works but `etree.iterparse()` fails due to an encoding error. I went through all the SO answers on iterparse() encoding but no one seems to have had this problem yet.